# Woocommerce: Set order status to complete when QR code (containing order id) is scanned

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, barcode-scanner

How can I show a simple form (similar to the search form) somewhere in the admin panel of Woocommerce (maybe as a separate menu entry) where I can just enter the order number and it sets that order (with that order number) to complete, without having to reload the page.

Why I need this: On my shipping labels there is a QR code containing the order number. When I scan that QR code it should set that order to complete (and thus notifying the customer that the order is now completed). As stated the form should work without having to reload the page after each scan, so that I can scan orders continuously.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding form submission without page reload, you have to submit the value using AJAX. jQuery has [$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) methods which you could use for this purpose.

Example (copied from [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var data = {
        'action': 'my_action',
        'whatever': ajax_object.we_value      // We pass php values differently!
    };
    // We can also pass the url value separately from ajaxurl for front end AJAX implementations
    jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
```

When the data is submitted, you have to make use of the `wp_ajax_(action)` to process the request.

Example (copied from [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)) :

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function my_enqueue($hook) {
    if( 'index.php' != $hook ) {
    // Only applies to dashboard panel
    return;
    }
        
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/js/my_query.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );

    // in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );
}

// Same handler function...
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
function my_action() {
    global $wpdb;
    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );
    $whatever += 10;
        echo $whatever;
    wp_die();
}
```

You can get detailed explanation from the official documentation : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

And, you could do the order status updation of an order using the `update_status()` function. Example:

```
$order_id = ''; //-- received from AJAX request
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);

if (!empty($order)) {
 $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}
```